# how can someone mention me and the bot says something, in discord js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So if people mention me, I want the bot to say "yo sup", I've used this code but the bot doesn't say anything I want the bot to say something back, I don't know what's wrong here

What should I fix in this code?

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
   
    if (message.content.startsWith("<@myid> ")) {
        message.channel.send('yo sup');
    }; 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Message#mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions). Use the [`.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) property from `Message#mentions` for this

```js
if (message.mentions.users.has("your_id")) {
    message.channel.send('yo sup');
}
```